# Avoid Data repetition in UITableView cells when scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xcode8

I need an  auto scrolling Image slider in top of viewcontroller followed by list of some entities(dynamic cells with image and title). To implement that I have taken a uitableview and I'm adding scrollview to my first cell, and my code is as follows

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    if indexPath.row  == 0{
       return 200
    }
    else {
       return 50
    }    
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 20    
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    if indexPath.row  == 0 {

       let sv = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.width, height: cell.frame.height))

       sv.auk.show(url: "url for image1")
       sv.auk.show(url: "url for image2")

       cell.addSubview(sv)
       print("inside if")
      }
      else {

       print("else")
       cell.textLabel?.text = "cool"
      }
      return cell                
}
```

I'm using [this](https://github.com/evgenyneu/Auk) repository to create image slider which creates slider on a scrollview, So for first cell I have added scrollview. But as you can see in the picture the image slider reappears on multiple rows. Please tell me what is the mistake that I'm doing.In case if there is any better approaches please suggest .

[image]

[image]

Comment: your "inside if" should be printed only once while scrolling down. Is it printing it multiple times in debugger?

Comment: When I scroll down it will print once and again when I scroll up. But not in all index as shown in image.

Answer (score 2):

Try taking a separate class for dynamic cells. Dequeue both the cells (static and dynamic cells) in the **cellForRow** method as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return indexPath.row == 0 ? 200 : 50
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return 20 }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.row  == 0 {

        let cell  = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

        scrollViewWidth = cell.frame.width
        scrollViewHeight = cell.frame.height
        let scrollView = prepareScrollView(width: scrollViewWidth, height: scrollViewHeight)
        cell.addSubview(scrollView )

        print("First row")
        return cell
       }
       else {

        let myCustomCell: MyCustomTableViewCellClass = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyCustomTableViewCellIdentieier", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomTableViewCellClass 
        myCustomCell.textLabel?.text = "Cool"

        print("Other dynamic rows")
        return myCustomCell
      }
}

func prepareScrollView(_ width: Float, height: Float) -> UIScrollView {

    let scrollViewFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: scrollViewFrame)
    scrollView.auk.show(url: "url for image1")
    scrollView.auk.show(url: "url for image2") 

    return scrollView
}
```

Take a separate class as **MyCustomTableViewCellClass** of type **UITableViewCell** and subclass your dynamic cell with this class. Don't forget to give cell identifier as "MyCustomTableViewCellIdentieier"

After this, your static cell will dequeue only once and no chances od repeating UI elements

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code in your table view cell class -

```
 override func prepareForReuse() {
    //set your lable and image view to nil
}
```

SideMenuTVCell is a my custom UITableViewCell class -

Hope like this you have your own class within this class you add `prepareForReuse()` method -

```
class SideMenuTVCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var iconIView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var lblTitle: UILabel!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

}

override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)  

}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    //set your lable and image view to nil

   self.iconIView.image = nil
   self.lblTitle.text = nil

 }

}
```

Comment: Hi prema can you give small code snippet which is using prepareForReuse()  in uitableview, I'm not getting where to add that.

Comment: Within your custom cell class.